# Axios is caching somehow my get user request react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm using Axios `("axios": "^0.19.0")` to do a GET request to my backend which works as I already tested it by sending the same token through Postman macOS app, and returns the correct user object.

But from my React Native app, whenever I do the get request and pass the same bearer token, I get the last user I logged in as a response.

This is how I'm sending the request:

```
getUserByToken: function(token) {
        var headers = [
            { key: 'Authorization', value: 'Bearer ' + token},
            { key: 'Content-Type', value: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            { key: 'Cache-Control', value: 'no-cache'}
        ];

        setHeaders('get', headers);
        return AxiosInstance.get('/user');
    },
```

The setHeaders method is used to set the headers to the request, I reset all http methods to an empty object and set the proper key-values for the following request.

```
export const setHeaders = (type, props) => {
    AxiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
        config.headers[type] = {};

        props.forEach((prop) => {
            config.headers[type][prop.key] = prop.value;
        });
        return config;
    });
}
```

As you can see, I even attempted to use Cache-Control: no-cache but still, keeps caching for no reason.

This is how I'm calling this function from my `AuthView.js`

```
 UserServices.getUserByToken(loginData.access_token)
        .then(userResponse => {
   // here userResponse is the previous user! 
   // even though i'm passing the correct token
            this.props.onSetUserInfo(userResponse.data);
            this.setState({
                loading: false
            }, () => {
                startMainTabs();
            });
        });
```

Why could this be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in dev console if the request is going or not?

Comment: @Tapas Okay so it looks like it might be an issue with Axios... even though i'm passing the new token, the request object in Reactotron is the previous token! wtf this is weird.

Comment: Ohhhh i think i know why it is!!! you see the setHeader there? it's kinda async, so sometimes it would send the http request first before setting or finishing to set the new headers, i need to do this with promises.

Comment: @msqar yeah the problem here is the code inside `setHeaders`, there's a callback happening that you aren't waiting for confirmation from before sending the request - even if it's sync, the callback will still run _after_ the request has gone

Comment: @James yes, can you help me to improve it please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue appears to be that the request is being sent before the header has actually been set. The reason for that is because `setHeader` internally relies on a callback to fire before actually setting the header, and theres no hook to allow the calling code to wait for this code to finish before firing off the request.

It's fixable though, make `setHeader` return a `Promise` and resolve with the `config` object

```
export const setHeaders = (type, props) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    AxiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
      config.headers[type] = {};
      props.forEach((prop) => {
        config.headers[type][prop.key] = prop.value;
      });
      return resolve(config);
    });
  });
}
```

Then in `getUserByToken`, `await` the header

```
getUserByToken: async function (token) {
  var headers = [
    { key: 'Authorization', value: 'Bearer ' + token},
    { key: 'Content-Type', value: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    { key: 'Cache-Control', value: 'no-cache'}
  ];

  await setHeaders('get', headers);
  return AxiosInstance.get('/user');
}
```

Comment: Trying to find why even though the promise seems to be correctly coded, it's not working. Debugging atm.

Comment: Couldn't make it work, but appears that i could make it work by setting them directly like this: props.forEach((prop) => {
        AxiosInstance.defaults.headers.common[prop.key] = prop.value;
    });

Comment: no, no error, but never got inside the `AxiosInstance.interceptors.request.use()` function, have no idea why, tried so many things, but didn't work. So i ended up setting them directly.

Comment: @msqar ah ok, well if there's a means of setting directly that doesn't require a callback then that's obviously better :)

Comment: I was also getting cached / old response .WIth the help of James answer, I did this:axios.get("API", {
        headers: {
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
        }
      }); And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with below code i have already tested same on my project and it's working fine.

```
getUserByToken: function(token) {
        var headers = [
            { key: 'Authorization', value: 'Bearer ' + token},
            { key: 'Content-Type', value: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            { key: 'Cache-Control', value: 'no-store'}
        ];

        setHeaders('get', headers);
        return AxiosInstance.get('/user');
    },
```

Use same above code it will solved your problem.